# How to get and update a list of all elements that have mouse event listeners && a pointer cursor?

Tags: javascript, performance, google-chrome-extension, dom-events, getcomputedstyle

elements that have a pointer cursor are either by default clickable elements like links and buttons, or elements that have their css property `cursor` set to `pointer`.

some optimizations are needed so not to naively and excessively call `getComputedstyle` and ruin [performance](https://gist.github.com/paulirish/5d52fb081b3570c81e3a), right?

is it gonna only require the monkey patching/wrapping of `add`/`removeEventListener` like how [Zone.js](https://github.com/angular/zone.js) does - to catch the adding and removing of events listeners on elements? and not need `getEventListeners` from `DOMDebugger` API.

in case you're wondering what's the use case,
it's to make [vimium](https://github.com/philc/vimium) show hints on all clickable elements it currently misses, it doesn't need and require dev tools permissions.

Comment: _“is it gonna only require the monkey patching/wrapping of add/removeEventListener”_ - if you only want to catch elements that were actually added (/removed) using those …? It’s likely not gonna catch any `<foo onclick="bar()">` this way.

Comment: Can you add any details like: code used, error problem encountered? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the community what you have tried.